# Android BLE app development--Scan list contains nothing on some phones

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth

I'm working on a BLE application for both ios and Android devices.

The application is written utilizing ionic and cordova.

On my Samsung Galaxy S6, Android version 6.0.1, my application will not populate the scan list even though I know I have devices advertising.  Other generic applications like BlueScan and Bluetooth LE Scanner run on this phone do populate the scan list as I believe they should.

I also have access to two other Android devices--Motorola MotoG and Samsung Galaxy Tab 4.  Both of these two devices will populate the scan list as desired running my application.

ios phones also populate the scan list appropriately.

Has anyone else run into such a problem with a Samsung Galaxy S6?  If so, were you able to determine if there was a modification required to the app's source code or some setting needing adjusting on the phone itself?

Answer (score 0):

An updated version to the BLE plugin we were using proved to have a fix for this issue.